# How to add a link to Wi-Fi on the Home Screen of Galaxy S8+

Tags: wi-fi, settings, home-screen-shortcuts

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S8+ (Android 9)

In order to get to list of available Wi-Fi networks, I must tap the gear for Settings (on the Home Screen), followed by a tap on "Connections", followed by a tap on "Wi-Fi", and then a tap on the name of the available network.

I already have a link to the Samsung gear for Settings on the home screen. Is there a way to add a link that takes me straight to the available Wi-Fi networks?

Tapping and holding the Settings gear on the Home Screen shows this:

[image]

In contrast, tapping and holding the Settings gear on a Nokia G20, running stock firmware with Android 12) shows this (the menu item for "Wi-Fi" can be dragged & dropped onto the Home Screen:

[image]

Also in contrast, tapping and holding the Settings gear on a Pixel 1, running Lineage 17, shows this (again, the menu item for "Wi-Fi" can be dragged & dropped onto the Home Screen:

[image]

Comment: I just checked my Galaxy M21, Android 12, and looks like Samsung did heavy modifications to the Settings app, including *not providing an app widget and home screen shortcuts for Settings*. This means that at least it might need a 3rd-party app (either a shortcut maker or automation app) to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android up to version 11 you can swipe down from the upper screen border to get the quick settings bar.

In quick settings there is the Wifi button (unless you removed it). Tap and hold the Wifi button and Android will open the WiFi network list in Android settings.